# capslock as additional control key for just one program on Windows

Tags: windows, capslock

How do I make Caps Lock key work as an additional Control key in just one program on Windows?

[similar thread for Aquamacs on Mac users](https://superuser.com/questions/40005/aquamacs-how-to-remap-capslock-to-meta-key-at-application-level)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AutoHotKey!](http://autohotkey.com)

Use the bundled window spy to grab the window class, and have a script that looks like:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class [the window class]
CapsLock::LCtrl
#IfWinActive
```